# Create Multiline Chart with Plotly

Tags: c#, plotly, .net-6.0

Using Net 6 and Plotly I have:

```
List<Int32> xValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 500);

List<Single> y1Values = getY1Values();

List<Single> y2Values = getY2Values();
```

How to create one Plotly.Net C# chart with 2 lines (for y1Values and for y2Values)?

I was only able to create with one set of y values:

```
GenericChart.GenericChart chart = Chart2D.Chart.Line<Int32, Single, String>(xValues, y1Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a chart for each line plot. Add them to a list, then create a new chart using `Chart.Combine`

```
var chartY1 = Chart2D.Chart.Line<int, Single, string>(xValues, y1Values);
var chartY2 = Chart2D.Chart.Line<int, Single, string>(xValues, y2Values);

var chartList = new List<GenericChart.GenericChart>();
chartList.Add(chartY1);
chartList.Add(chartY2);

var combinedChart = Chart.Combine(list);
```